# .NET Core console app throws MissingManifestResourceException when consumes Clipr package

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am building a demo project on Windows that consumes Clipr nuget package. I get a runtime exception that I am not sure how to fix. Where do I start debugging it? The code of the POC is as simple as this:

**Source**

```
using System;
using clipr;

namespace CliprTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parsed = CliParser.StrictParse<Options>(args);

            Console.WriteLine("Ran without params first");
        }
    }

    [ApplicationInfo(Description = "Test")]
    public class Options
    {
    }
}
```

**Ouput**

```
soloy@DESKTOP-MRND0KT MINGW64 /c/GitHub/CliprTest/src/CliprTest
$ dotnet build && dotnet run bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/CliprTest.dll
Project CliprTest (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because inputs were modified
Compiling CliprTest for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:02.2712506


Project CliprTest (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.

Unhandled Exception: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException:
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "clipr.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "clipr.NetCore" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at clipr.Usage.AutomaticHelpGenerator`1.get_UsageTitle()
   at clipr.Usage.AutomaticHelpGenerator`1.GetUsage(IParserConfig config)
   at clipr.CliParser`1.StrictParse(String[] args)
   at clipr.CliParser.StrictParse[TS](String[] args)
   at CliprTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I did open an [issue on Clipr's github repo](https://github.com/nemec/clipr/issues/40) but not sure how soon I will get an answer and whether the issue is on my side

Comment: Since you got an answer on GitHub, would you consider posting it as an answer here and then accepting it?

Comment: @svick just did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClipR nuget package that supports .NET core was not officially published (basically, hidden in nuget feed list).
With the release of v1.6.0 this issue was resolved.